# Collecting all codes and the associated descriptive text in R / scraping?

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping

On this link: https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/jelCodes.php?view=jel#P
I am trying to collect all the codes and put them in a table with the code description next to it.
So the table will look like this

```
column1 Column2
A1      General Economics
A10     General
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

How can I do that in R? I am pretty sure it has something with scraping from the html version of the site using some sort of str_extract_all() but I am not sure how to proceed or if that is even the most efficient way

I am pretty sure it has something with scraping from the html version of the site using some sort of str_extract_all() but I am not sure how to proceed or if that is even the most efficient way

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky to capture the url you list because it needs a java rendering that usually happens on the browser. Nonetheless, if you capture the "for print" of this particular page, rendering is done on the server, making things easier for us.

Try:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)


obj_html <- read_html(x = 'https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/jelCodes.php?view=econlit&print')

df <- obj_html |> 
  html_elements(xpath = "//div[@id]//table") |> 
  html_table() %>% as.data.frame() |>
  rename(code = X1, description = X2) |> 
  filter(code != "") |>
  as_tibble() #Optional, just for the better look of a tibble over a data.frame

# A tibble: 859 × 2
   code  description                                                 
   <chr> <chr>                                                       
 1 A00   General Economics and Teaching                              
 2 A10   General Economics: General                                  
 3 A11   Role of Economics; Role of Economists; Market for Economists
 4 A12   Relation of Economics to Other Disciplines                  
 5 A13   Relation of Economics to Social Values                      
 6 A14   Sociology of Economics                                      
 7 A19   General Economics: Other                                    
 8 A20   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: General       
 9 A21   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: Pre-college   
10 A22   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: Undergraduate
```

Answer (score 0):

Top section of the page also lists XML files for convenient (well.. more or less) data exchange:

```r
cl_xml <- xml2::read_xml("https://www.aeaweb.org/econlit/classifications.xml") 
xml2::as_list(cl_xml)[[1]] |>
  dplyr::bind_rows() |>
  tidyr::unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 859 × 2
#>    code  description                                                 
#>    <chr> <chr>                                                       
#>  1 A00   General Economics and Teaching                              
#>  2 A10   General Economics: General                                  
#>  3 A11   Role of Economics; Role of Economists; Market for Economists
#>  4 A12   Relation of Economics to Other Disciplines                  
#>  5 A13   Relation of Economics to Social Values                      
#>  6 A14   Sociology of Economics                                      
#>  7 A19   General Economics: Other                                    
#>  8 A20   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: General       
#>  9 A21   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: Pre-college   
#> 10 A22   Economic Education and Teaching of Economics: Undergraduate 
#> # ℹ 849 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: great thanks so the url you're using takes you to a pdf with the codes in it rather than using the html. thanks